# testing grep -r using subprocess.Popen on python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im trying to test python and using this command. Iam trying to emulate the following command lines.

`grep -r "any string" . -B1 or  grep -r --include=*.xml "any string" -B1`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

#subprocess.call("ls -l", shell=True)


message_type = raw_input('Enter Something:' )
print'"{}"'.format(message_type)
subprocess.Popen(['grep -r', message_type, '.', '-B1'], shell=True)
```

Comment: its working now  I treated grep -r as one I should have separated it and switching shell = False

Answer (score 1):

Specify `grep`, `-r` as separated items:

```
subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-r', message_type, '.', '-B1'], shell=True)
```

Otherwise `grep -r` is considered as a program instead of `grep`.

Comment: With this fix, `shell=False` would make more sense.

Comment: nice it did work grabbing loc of falsetru and switching shell=False